# GET request to server `http://desktopName` over LAN through mobile

Tags: android, node.js, http, mobile, get

My app is trying to lock desktop's mouse and keyboard using a mobile app, which is already working.

I am already using the desktop IP but now trying to use `http://desktopName` as `GET URL` for my android app but it is not working.

I am using Framework7 `app.request.get` for my client.

## CLIENT

```
    // var server = "http://192.168.31.147:8089" // working in mobile browser and app
    var server = "http://desktop-s5n5hiq:8089" // not working in mobile browser and app
    
    $$("#server").html(server)
    app.request.get(server+"/connect").then((res) => {
      var data = res.data
```

I am using node `http` module for my server.

## SERVER

This server is already working without issue.

```
var http = require('http');
var host = "desktop-s5n5hiq"
var port = 8089


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
...
}).listen(port,host,()=>{
    console.log("running server: http://"+host+":"+port)
});
```

My server IP is constantly changing because my router has no IP lock or IP reservation option, that's why I want to use the desktop name instead (`http://desktopName`), however, I am not getting any response from my server when I use the desktopName

These are already working:

1. Connect to `http://desktopName` using desktop and laptop browser
2. Connect to IPs `http://192.168.1.*` using desktop, laptop and mobile browser
   [image]

[image: Working - tab using server IP]

Not working:

1. Connect to `http://desktopName` using mobile browser. (No "Desktop is connected" log) [image: NOT WORKING - GET request to]

Any comment is much appreciated.

## Edited:

I forgot to mention that we have 2 routers one is an extender. The main one has this `192.168.1.1` DNS server, however, the other has `192.168.31.1`. During desktop boot, it sometimes connects to the main router and sometimes to the extender.

I have tried this solution https://kb.netgear.com/27476/How-do-I-set-a-static-IP-address-in-Windows (added `192.168.1.5`) but I think it will cause an issue if the PC connected to the extender.

Comment: You do not have to mess around with your router. Just give your PC a static/fixed ip instead of using DHCP.

Comment: Hi sir, I have edited my question since you mentioned about static IP.

Comment: The pc cannot -be connected- or connect to the extender if you give it that ip ...1.5.

Comment: Currently, my pc is connected to the extender since the main router has a slow connection on this part of the house, if I use the extender and put `192.168.31.5` for example, and in any case, the extender was turned off leaving the main router, will my PC get an IP from there? Just asking about a scenario since sometimes they are turning the extender off if the internet becomes too slow in the main router.

Comment: No. If you give the pc a fixed ip it can only connect to the one serving that ip. DCHP will not work then.